# Typing with keyof and template literal

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

For each arbitrary object, e.g.

```js
{
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

I'd like to have a type e.g.:

```js
type ConsumerFn<T> = (value: T) => void;
type Consumer = {
  nameConsumer: ConsumerFn<string>;
  ageConsumer: ConsumerFn<number>;
}
```

How can I make this typing generic?
I'm imaging:

```js
type Consumer<T> = {
  [`${K in keyof T}Consumer`]: ConsumerFn<K>
}
```

but that does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following mapping type should work, transforming the properties into your template literals is a bit verbose

```
type ConsumerFn<T> = (value: T) => void;

type Consumer<Type> = {
    [Property in keyof Type as `${string & Property}Consumer`]: ConsumerFn<Type[Property]>
};

type Foo = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

type FooConsumer = Consumer<Foo>;
```

Results in

```
type FooConsumer = {
   nameConsumer: ConsumerFn<string>;
   ageConsumer: ConsumerFn<number>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
type ConsumerGeneric<T> = keyof T extends string ? {
  [K in keyof T as `${K}Consumer`]: ConsumerFn<T>
} : never;
```